# Insert ScrollView in TableView?

Tags: iphone

I have a TableView with one cell and I want to insert in this cell a lot of text so I think I'll need to use a ScrollView for scroll the text.

How can I insert? Is correct this method?

This is a help in the application, is correct use this modality?

Sorry but I'm a beginner and I don't have an iPhone or iPod, thanks!

Comment: What is the need of a table view? If you are just going to have once cell showing large text why don't you use UITextView?

Answer (score 1):

While I concur with 7KV7's original comment, it doesn't look like there is need of a tableview in this scenario...

Just in case someone else happens upon this looking for an answer to the "Scrollview in a Tableview" question here are few clarifying points for the above comments.

The technical problem with having a tableview and a scrollview together on the same view is that UITableView is already a descendent of UIScrollView and if you attempt to handle both in the same view then you will end up with quite a mess with conflicting delegate messages.

As suggested by iPhonePgr, you can create a custom UITableViewCell.  The first thought would be to let the UITableViewCell act as the delegate for it's own scroll view.  The problem here is that the cell and it's contents could be discarded or reused at any moment as part of tableview's dequeue functionality.

So some ground rules to guide your implementation:

1. Whatever your solution, you're probably going to end up making a custom controller class, possibly derived from NSObject and implementing UIScrollViewDelegate.
2. The custom controller object acts as the mediator between the model object and the cell.
3. You will probably have an array or array-of-arrays that mirrors the model hierarchy driving the UITableView structure.
4. Because the cells can be discarded at any time you will have restore the scroll view state on cell initialization and preserve the state has part of handling your delegate actions or through a custom UITableViewCell implementing prepareForReuse.

Hopefully these points will come in useful to anyone who runs across this entry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom cell by inheriting UITableViewCell and then add UIScrollView in the customcell. Then Use that cell in the Table view.

Answer (score 0):

you can put your text in `UITextView` and add it as a subview in your `UITableViewCell`,because

```
    UITextView is inherited from UIScrollView, 
No need to add UIScrollView if you use UITextView
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create UITableView you implement a number of delegate method which you can see by pressing the window key and then double clicking the UITableView delegate . In one of the methods you can set the cell height as per your requirement. By doing this your cell height can vary.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)resultTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    
{    

    return 150;    

}
```

As your table has a defined height, when the text in cell will be too much to contain into a scrollview will be automatically inserted.